# Can't boot in Windows 10 2004: black screen after dell logo

Tags: windows-10, boot, mbr, diskpart, windows-10-v2004

Yesterday everything was fine and I haven't change anything in the mean time, but this morning, my computer can't boot anymore. When booting, the dell logo is displayed and the dell line is loading, then a black screen appears with a dash flashing for 2 or 3 times in the top left corner and then nothing happens. I get a black screen forever with the fan going crazy. When I press ctrl+alt+del, my computer reboot, and the same problem goes again.

---

Update: I was able to login windows after doing a `chkdsk C: /f /r /x` which found several orphan file, fixed some files system and found a bad cluster.
At the following reboot I was able to pass the windows logo but then I got a BSOD with `critical process died` error

---

I tried:

1. to remove every devices connected,  the charger, the battery and I pressed the power button for 20 seconds
2. using a cmd from a windows recovery USB (created this morning):

- in `diskpart`: the `system reserve partition` was assigned to the letter `C` and the `main windows partition` was assigned to the letter `F`, *which suprised me because I know that my windows partition was on `C`*. After following the step on this [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/3103656/an-operating-system-wasn-t-found-error-when-booting-windows), the letter were reversed with the `main windows partition` assigned to `C` and the `system reserve partition` assigned to `F`.
- still following the link above I did
  `bcdboot C:\Windows /s c: /f ALL`    which resulted in `bfsvc error could not open the bcd template store`
- then I tried  `bcdboot c:\windows /v /s c: /f ALL`  (notice the /v) which told me that boot was succesfully copied but I still have the same boot problem
- I tried this command with either the `C:` (main windows) partition set as active and the `F:` (system reserve) partition set as active. (*After reading many answer I am confused about which one should be set active*)

Still in cmd of windows RE:

- `bootrec /fixmbr`: the operation completed succesfully
- `bootrec /fixboot`: first I got `element not found`, but now, after doing the dispart thing above, I am getting `the volume does not contain a recognized file system`
- `bootsect /nt60 c: /mbr`: `bootcode was successfully updated on all targeted volumes`
- `bootrec /rebuiltbcd`: 2 windows installed are found, one in `C:\Window` and one in `C:\Windows.old` (I have updated to Windows 10 2004 a week ago), but I didn't have any boot problem for a week after the update, except today): I choose Y to add the first install to teh but table and N for the second wibdows install : but I get the error `The requested system device cannot be found`
- `scf /scannow`: no problem are found
- I can't find a way to start in safe mode (the option is not in the recovery menu)

I have also used the `ubuntu boot repair` which didn't solved anything

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In brief: it was cause by an hard drive failure.

I was able to start windows after running a `chckdsk c: /f /r /x` command (it took 3.5h). The I could login, Windows looks normal. But when I restarted it the day after I got the same error. The `chckdsk` command said that there was multiple orphaned and unindexed files and a bad clusters so I guess my hard drive failed. I solved it by using a new hard drive and reinstalling my last windows image backup.

When browsing my hard drive via a ubuntu live usb (to recover the last version of some files), one of the folder was inaccessible which seems to confirms the HD failure hypothesis.

But it's strange since I ran `chckdsk` to fully check the hard drive (SDD SATA3) health few weeks before, and it did not detect any problem. Did the windows update 2004 broke my harddrive?

Answer (score 0):

You have done too many manipulations and may have increased the already-existing
damage to the disk.

I suggest to:

1. Backup your data
2. [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html),
   and if this doesn't help:
3. Reinstall Windows from scratch.